# Lint rule for number of injections in a constructor

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, lint

I'm trying to create a Lint rule in my Android code that checks the number if injections in a constructor, so if I exceed a certain number for a view model, for example, I will raise a lint warning.

I know that I have to implement a UastScanner in my Lint Detector, but I am getting lost because I cannot find good documentation. Has someone else ever done something like this? Or where can I find good deocumentation about it?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe lint rules are one of the least documented things around Android. I find it best to have a [look at the existing ones](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks) and going from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*** NOTE - Read entire answer for edited solution. ***

I was able to write the UAST conversion like so:

```
public class NumberOfDependenciesInjectedDetector extends Detector implements Detector.UastScanner {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_INJECTIONS_ALLOWED = 5;
    private static final Class<? extends Detector> DETECTOR = NumberOfDependenciesInjectedDetector.class;
    private static final EnumSet<Scope> SCOPE = Scope.JAVA_FILE_SCOPE;
    private static final Implementation IMPLEMENTATION = new Implementation(DETECTOR, SCOPE);

    public static final Issue ISSUE = Issue.create(
            "NumberOfDependenciesInjected",
            "Limit number of injections in a class via constructor",
            "A longer description here",
            Category.CORRECTNESS,
            10,
            Severity.ERROR,
            IMPLEMENTATION
    );

    @Override
    public List<Class<? extends UElement>> getApplicableUastTypes() {
        return Collections.<Class<? extends UElement>>singletonList(UClass.class);
    }

    @Override
    public UElementHandler createUastHandler(JavaContext context) {
        return new ConstructorVisitor(context);
    }

    private static class ConstructorVisitor extends UElementHandler {

        private JavaContext javaContext;

        private ConstructorVisitor(JavaContext javaContext) {
            this.javaContext = javaContext;
        }

        @Override
        public void visitClass(UClass clazz){
            UMethod[] methods = clazz.getMethods();

            for(UMethod method : methods){
                if(!method.isConstructor()) continue;

                if (method.getParameterList().getParametersCount() > NUMBER_OF_INJECTIONS_ALLOWED) {
                    javaContext.report(ISSUE, method, javaContext.getLocation(method), "Injections exceed allowed value of " + NUMBER_OF_INJECTIONS_ALLOWED);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, it seems that this still doesn't pick up Kotlin source files... very confusing.

EDIT: 12/19/17 - FIXED

The problem was two-fold:

1) There was indeed a hidden usage of a Psi method that was blocking the check from working.  The visitClass method should not use getParameterList() but instead, getUastParameters().  Replace visitclass above with:

```
@Override
public void visitClass(UClass clazz){
    UMethod[] methods = clazz.getMethods();

    for(UMethod method : methods){
        if(!method.isConstructor()) continue;

        if (method.getUastParameters().size() > NUMBER_OF_INJECTIONS_ALLOWED) {
            javaContext.report(ISSUE, clazz, javaContext.getLocation(method), "Injections exceed allowed value of " + NUMBER_OF_INJECTIONS_ALLOWED);
        }
    }
}
```

2) After speaking with Tor Norbye directly on the lint-dev group, he pointed out that Android Studio 3.0 in fact lint does not work externally with kotlin and therefore was not expected to work as described here.  Upgrading to Android Studio 3.1 Canary and running the linter produced the expected report.

Comment: I suspect the problem is with the Scope.JAVA_FILE_SCOPE.  However, none of the other scopes seem to work including Scope.ALL...  In anything but JAVA_FILE_SCOPE the linter doesn't report the offending files.

Comment: ONLY other thing I can think of is that there is some accidental PSI usage in this snippet but I sure don't see where.  The result of that would be only java files working.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to find a solution using JavaScanner, but I haven't found anything yet using UastScanner (which it is what I want to use, since we have Kotlin classes too):

```
public class NumberOfDependenciesInjectedDetector extends Detector implements Detector.JavaScanner {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_INJECTIONS_ALLOWED = 5;
    private static final Class<? extends Detector> DETECTOR = NumberOfDependenciesInjectedDetector.class;
    private static final EnumSet<Scope> SCOPE = Scope.JAVA_FILE_SCOPE;
    private static final Implementation IMPLEMENTATION = new Implementation(DETECTOR, SCOPE);

    public static final Issue ISSUE = Issue.create(
            "NumberOfDependenciesInjected",
            "Limit number of injections in a class via constructor",
            "A longer description here",
            Category.CORRECTNESS,
            10,
            Severity.ERROR,
            IMPLEMENTATION
    );

    @Override
    public boolean appliesTo(Context context, File file) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Speed getSpeed(Issue issue) {
        return Speed.FAST;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Class<? extends Node>> getApplicableNodeTypes() {
        return Collections.<Class<? extends Node>>singletonList(ConstructorDeclaration.class);
    }

    @Override
    public AstVisitor createJavaVisitor(JavaContext context) {
        return new ConstructorVisitor(context);
    }

    private static class ConstructorVisitor extends ForwardingAstVisitor {

        private JavaContext javaContext;

        private ConstructorVisitor(JavaContext javaContext) {
            this.javaContext = javaContext;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean visitConstructorDeclaration(ConstructorDeclaration node) {
            if (node.astParameters().size() > NUMBER_OF_INJECTIONS_ALLOWED) {
                javaContext.report(ISSUE, node, javaContext.getLocation(node), "My message goes here");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```